# Why this Query takes such a long time to execute

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have three tables

- glSalesJournal
- HMISAdd
- HMISMain

Now what i am trying to do is add the glSalesJournal amt with HMISAdd amt while grouping up with various Fields and inserting the result into glSalesJournal

The glSalesJournal contains 633173 records

The HMISAdd contains 4193 records

HMISAdd and glSalesJournal contains the same columns which are

- loc
- glAcct
- glSubAcct
- batchNbr
- contractNbr
- amt

I added indexes to the table still the results are the same.

Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO hmismain
            (loc,
             glacct,
             subacct,
             batchnbr,
             contractnbr,
             amt)
SELECT glsalesjournal.loc,
       glsalesjournal.glacct,
       glsalesjournal.glsubacct,
       ( glsalesjournal.amt + hmisadd.amt ) AS sumAmt,
       glsalesjournal.batchnbr,
       glsalesjournal.salescontnbr
FROM   glsalesjournal
       LEFT OUTER JOIN hmisadd
                    ON ( glsalesjournal.loc = hmisadd.loc
                         AND glsalesjournal.glacct = hmisadd.glacct
                         AND glsalesjournal.glsubacct = hmisadd.subacct
                         AND glsalesjournal.batchnbr = hmisadd.batchnbr
                         AND glsalesjournal.salescontnbr = hmisadd.contractnbr )
GROUP  BY glsalesjournal.loc,
          hmisadd.loc,
          glsalesjournal.glacct,
          hmisadd.glacct,
          glsalesjournal.glsubacct,
          hmisadd.subacct,
          glsalesjournal.batchnbr,
          hmisadd.batchnbr,
          glsalesjournal.salescontnbr,
          hmisadd.contractnbr
```

The time taken by the script to execute is more than 2 hours. Even when I limit the Records to 100 the time taken is the same.

Can someone please guide me how can I optimize the script.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean **sum(** glSalesJournal.amt + HMISAdd.amt) as sumAmt,

Comment: @nonnb, if I'm not wrong I think he means **(** glSalesJournal.amt + HMISAdd.amt) as sumAmt

Comment: yes ( glsalesjournal.amt + hmisadd.amt ) AS sumAmt is what i want... the sum of two fields... either way the output comes fine.

Comment: @ankit: What are the Primary keys of the 2 tables? Are the combinations you are joining on, Primary or Unique?

Comment: @ypercube there is a composite primary key made out of the fields which are grouped... I mean my primary key is composed of loc
glAcct,
glSubAcct,
batchNbr,
contractNbr,
amt

Comment: This is the primary key in both tables?

Comment: @ypercube yes these are the primary keys in both the tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It looks like it's a one off query, am I correct here? If not than you are inserting the same data into hmismain table every time.
2) You are grouping on fields from **TWO** separate tables, so no amount of indexing will ever help you. The **ONLY** index that will help is an index over a view linking these two tables in the same way.

Further note:
What is the point of

```
      GROUP  BY glsalesjournal.loc,
      hmisadd.loc,
      glsalesjournal.glacct,
      hmisadd.glacct,
      glsalesjournal.glsubacct,
      hmisadd.subacct,
      glsalesjournal.batchnbr,
      hmisadd.batchnbr,
      glsalesjournal.salescontnbr,
      hmisadd.contractnbr
```

You are grouping the data by the same fields twice
`glsalesjournal.loc,           hmisadd.loc`
`glsalesjournal.glacct,          hmisadd.glacct,`
...

Remove the duplicates from GROUP BY and it should run fast

Comment: Aelington  ok I removed the duplicate grouping still the query is slow. When i change left outer join to inner the script took almost 1 min.

Comment: @ankitsuhail Is that good or bad? What did you expect? With OUTER JOIN you have 633173 records to process, with INNER JOIN just 4193 records.  Post the actual SQL that you are running and table indexes definitions. There si something VERY wrong with your query or your set-up.  BTW: what is the number of records being inserted into hmismain? And are you absolutely sure that you need to run this query without any selection criteria every time?  If hmismain has any constrains (like unique keys) it maybe failing most of the time and it takes considerably more time than checking.

Comment: nice answer and thanks for telling me that i was building the query with a wrong approch but i did something different to get what I wanted. i will post the solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add an index on this fields:

```
glSalesJournal.loc
glSalesJournal.glAcct
glSalesJournal.glSubAcct
glSalesJournal.batchNbr
glSalesJournal.salesContNbr
HMISAdd.Loc
HMISAdd.GlAcct
HMISAdd.SubAcct
HMISAdd.batchNbr 
HMISAdd.contractNbr
```

If this fields are unindexed, it will perform fulltable scan for each individual record thus causing slow performance.

**[MySQL Create Index Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)**

Comment: The point is that OP can **not** add index(es) on these fields simply because they are from different tables. Unless OP will create a view they can't.  Further more the fields are duplicated in pairs as they are JOIN fields -> they will contain the same data -> one can be omitted from each pair.